Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences of real numbers. Suppose $a_0=b_0=-1$, $a_1=b_1$
Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences of real numbers. Suppose $a_0=b_0=-1$, $a_1=b_1$ and for $n\in\{2,3,...,11\}$
$a_n=a_{n-1}-(11-n)^2(1-(11-(n-1))^2)a_{n-2}$
$b_n=b_{n-1}-(12-n)^2(1-(12-(n-1))^2)b_{n-2}$
If $b_{11}=2a_{11},$ then find the value of $a_1$
My attempt:
$a_n-(11-(n-1))^2a_{n-1}=(1-(11-(n-1))^2)(a_{n-1}-(11-n)^2a_{n-2})$
The form looks good but I don't know how to go further.
Edit:
The answer should be $\frac{843}{7}$, but still don't know how to get this answer.

You seem to need to be able to define $a_2,b_2.$ Did you mean $n\in{2,3,\dots,11}?$

Yes thank you. My mistake, has been corrected. @ThomasAndrews

Where did you get the problem from? Running some numbers I found $b_{11}/a_{11}$ to be bounded by 0.01

Just find $a_{11},b_{11}$ when $a_1$ is 0 and 1, use linearity to get both of them as functions of $a_1$ and solve the linear equations.

It is a question from a math tournament. I just got the answer should be $\frac{843}{7}$, but still don't know the approach to the answer. @AdamDougall

UPDATE(solved):
I have found that $a_{n}-(1-(11-n)^2)a_{n-1}=(11-n)^2a_{n-1}-(11-n)^2(1-(11-(n-1))^2)a_{n-2}=(11-n)^2(a_{n-1}-(1-(11-(n-1))^2)a_{n-2})$
so that if $\ t_n=a_{n}-(1-(11-n)^2)a_{n-1}$ then $\ t_n=(11-n)^2t_{n-1}$ and $\ \frac{t_{10}}{t_1}=(9!)^2$
we also have $\ t_{10}=a_{10}=a_{11}$ and $\ t_{1}=a_1-99$
For $b_n$ we can get a similar form, which leads to $\ q_{11}=b_{11}$ and $\ q_{1}=b_1-120$ and $\ \frac{q_{11}}{q_1}=(10!)^2$
The simultaneous equations can be solved to find the answer.
